# MinMaxScaler makes my prediction flat

Tags: deep-learning, statistics, visualization, data-science-model, forecasting

I am trying to do univariate forecasting. But when i try to use MinMax Scaler my predictions are being flat (tried to use different activation functions) but when i use Standart Scaler my predictions are just fine.  How is this possible??

[image: Picture]

My model architecture:

````
EPOCHS = 1000

steps = int( np.ceil(x_train_multi.shape[0] / batch_size) )
val_steps=int( np.ceil(x_val_multi.shape[0] / batch_size) )


multi_step_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
multi_step_model.add(LSTM(128,activation="relu",return_sequences=False,input_shape=x_train_multi.shape[-2:]))
multi_step_model.add(Dropout(0.4))
multi_step_model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(future_target)) # for 72 outputs
multi_step_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(), loss='mae')

multi_step_model.summary()
print(train_data_multi)

multi_step_history = multi_step_model.fit(train_data_multi, epochs=EPOCHS,
                                          steps_per_epoch=steps,
                                          validation_data=val_data_multi,
                                          validation_steps=val_steps)
```
````

Comment: can you give some insights on range of true values?

Comment: @Uday its between -2,+3.

Comment: Which model are you using?

Comment: @Uday added to question